# Vuex with nuxtjs access store from JS file

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

I have a JS file called `axios.js` and I'm using interceptors to get the available languages from every API call I make, and store the available languages in an array called `comingLangs[]`
My question is how can I store this array inside my store so I can use it in my nuxt project?
the `import {store} from './store'` does not work I get an error : `Cannot find module './store'`

here is my code :

`plugins/axios.js`

```
import {store} from './store' //Not working
export default function ({$axios, i18n}, inject) {
  let comingLangs=[]
  const apiClient = $axios.create({
    headers: {
      'X-localization': i18n.locale,
    }

  });
 
  inject('apiClient', apiClient);
  apiClient.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    //Check if the response has meta_tags
    if (response.data.content.meta_tags !== undefined && response.data.content.meta_tags) {
      // store the languages from response to an array
      comingLangs = Object.keys(response.data.content.meta_tags.alternative)
     
      store.commit("SET_AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES",comingLangs)  // here is where I want to store comingLangs
    }
    return response
  });
}
```

`store/index.js`

```
export const state = () => ({
  availableLanguages: [],
})
export const mutations = {
 SET_AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES(state, payload) {
    state.availableLanguages = payload
  },
}
```

Comment: In here: export default function ({$axios, i18n}, inject) you are destructing the first parameter which is {$axios, i18n} . Try this: export default function (app, inject) { console.log(app) ... and check what app has inside it. Store might be there as a property. It can be $store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have been able to solve it by passing [app](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/context#app) as an argument to my function and using store from `app` like this :

```
export default function ({$axios, app, i18n}, inject) {
  let comingLangs=[]
  const apiClient = $axios.create({
    headers: {
      'X-localization': i18n.locale,
    }

  });
 
  inject('apiClient', apiClient);
  apiClient.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    //Check if the response has meta_tags
    if (response.data.content.meta_tags !== undefined && response.data.content.meta_tags) {
      // store the languages from response to an array
      comingLangs = Object.keys(response.data.content.meta_tags.alternative)
     
      app.store.commit("SET_AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES",comingLangs)  
    }
    return response
  });
}
```